# flatpak and recent files

Tags: libreoffice, flatpak

With my flatpak version of LibreOffice (LO 5.2.5, Ubuntu 18.04), the files created or modified by LO **do not appear in "Recent files" in Ubuntu**.
It seems to be the same for other applications (I tested also Sublime Text which is installed via flatpak).
It is quite annoying as Ubuntu "Recent files" is often the fastist way to find the files you recently work on.
How can this behavior be corrected?

Comment: It can be corrected by filing a bug report with each Flatpak author. They are failing to register their activity with Gnome properly.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**: the following is for the flatpak version of Gimp, but possibly also relevant to other flatpak apps.

The standard file used by well-behaved applications is `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`. Unfortunately the flatpak installs keep their own copy as `~/.var/app/{application}/data/recently-used.xbel`.

A first idea is to replace `~/.var/app/{application}/data/recently-used.xbel` by a link to `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` but this link is quickly replaced by a plain file.

On the other hand the `~/.var/app/{application}/data` directory has the same organization as `~/.local/share/` and replacing it by a (soft) link to `~/.local/share/` (and possibly copying over useful stuff) did correct the problem for me.

Comment: As far as I have observed, the Recent file problem concerns all applications installed with flatpak and with snap, and is linked to the sandboxing, so we need a general way of solving the problem.

Comment: @SilvainDupertuis The general way will come from the flatpak authors. If you want a flatpak fix, [report the issue](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues). By asking here you can only get work-arounds. Another annoying thing is the application-specific `/tmp`. Many apps communicate with others by putting the data in a `/tmp` file and passing the name.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have opened an issue in flatpak on github